# Can i cache a parent in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have this code:

```
Business.all.limit(50).each do |business|
  card = {name: business.name, logo: business.logo, category: business.category.name}
  feed << card
end
```

In my models, `Business` belongs to `Category`, and `Category` has many `Business`

My problem is that this will query the DB 50 times, each time I want to retrieve each business' category name.

I have seen Rails cache effectively by using :include, but all examples I have seen are for child records, for example:

```
Category.all :include => [:businesses]
```

but in this case I want to cache the parent's data.

Answer (score 1):

Its the same you can do by using singular model name

```
Business.includes(:category)
```